# Can an airliner land safely using only propulsion control?

Tags: airliner, landing, jet, fighter, propulsion

In [this](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88794main_PCA.pdf) amazing story ,after losing all hydraulic power of the aircraft , Captain Al Haynes guided the plane to the Sioux city, crashed but saved 185 of the 296 lives (United Airlines Flight 232-Sioux City, 1989). After this incident, NASA started to work on PCA systems. 
[image]
Gordon Fullerton landed an F-15, using only engine power. How did the F-15 land while the airliner crashed? Since an airliner and a fighter jet have different engine positions honestly it would make more sense to me if the airliner made it to the ground but fighter couldn't because it has relatively greater distance between engines, so better capability of yawing and as a result of having a shorter wingspan a fighter needs to fly faster to stay airborne. I understand the weight difference, i understand the possibility of adverse weather conditions during 232 flight, but i still don't get how a fighter is more capable than an airliner.

Comment: The main assumption is flawed, there are many cases of airliners landed after an hydraulical failure

Comment: @FredLarson I did check that , but that is a test flight , I wonder what would happen in a situation where a modern airliner is fully loaded.

Comment: I think in the SUX incident they had directional control down. The problem was lack of flaps, air brakes, spoilers, brakes or reverse thrust. They touched down at over 200 kt and 1800 ft/min sink rate. Haynes tried to throttle up at the last minute to attempt some kind of a flare, but one engine responded quicker than the other causing a roll that made the right wing hit the ground first.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I checked most of topics similar to this , someone edited the title, and it now looks like a duplicate topic , but the content/question is different.

Comment: Gotcha - I probably should have just noted it as related. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/can-pilots-land-an-aircraft-with-only-the-use-of-throttles

Comment: In the case of UA232, the horizontal stabilizers had been damaged and there was a continuous tendency to turn right (that's from the report.) According to Wikipedia, fully asymmetric thrust only barely corrected this. That doesn't leave much margin for any other control actions.

Comment: Q: So, what is your opinion on landing at Sioux City? A: It SUX.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Well, landing at Rapid City is KRAP.

Comment: in the 747 crash in Japan in 1985, the rudder was severed from the fuselage and the pilots managed to keep the plane in the air for about 20 minutes after the failure by differential throttle. However, they could not fully control the plane this way and it eventually flew into a mountain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some airliners have in fact landed more or less successfully using only engine power for control. The [2003 DHL attempted shootdown incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_Baghdad_DHL_attempted_shootdown_incident) is an example.

A major difference between United 232 and Fullerton's landings you cite is that Fullerton was working for NASA testing a system designed specifically for the purpose of assisting pilots in controlling an aircraft with power alone. United 232 had no such system. See https://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/news/FactSheets/FS-041-DFRC.html

Comment: Apparently, I missed the point that F-15 had PCA system specifically built for differential thrust assistance. Thanks!