# Why do twin-engine Diamond aircraft have a single FADEC lever instead of two engine throttles?

Tags: multi-engine, fadec

From my understanding, if you have a twin-engine aircraft with 2 lever engine throttle one for each engine you will be able to use differential thrust to steer in case of steering malfunction.

I don't understand why twin-engine Diamond aircraft decide to go with only single lever FADEC.

Here is the video I encounter that lead to this question.

Answer (score 8):

The DA 42 and DA 62 aircraft do not have throttle levers, they have power levers.  And the DA-42 and 62 have two power levers, one for each engine.  See the picture of the DA-62 cockpit below.

[image]

The cockpit images that you see there in the video are from the DA 40 NG airplane, which uses a single power lever for its turbo Diesel engine.

The reason for including two power levers is 1) independent control of engine power for each engine in the event of an engine failure 2) use of differential thrust for slipping in crosswind landings and 3) differential thrust to assist while turning on the ground.

Comment: @JanHudec commented under another (now-deleted) answer -- "Note that even non-FADEC engines would only have one power lever rather than throttle + mixture that gasoline engines have, because diesel does not have throttle and only meters fuel. On gasoline engine FADEC could automatically control mixture to dispense with it too, but on diesel it mainly prevents stalling the engine by abrupt power lever movement and adjusts timing to improve efficiency."

Comment: This answer leads us back to this tangentially-related question -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50486/how-can-using-split-throttles-help-when-landing-twins-in-crosswinds